# How can I get image file size which selected by UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know that the image file size in IPhone PhotoAlbum which selected by UIImagePickerController.

I've tried this code with 1,571,299 byte jpeg image.

```
UIIamge *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

NSData *imageData; 
if ( /* PNG IMAGE */ ) 
    imageData = UIImagePNGReprensentation(selectedImage);
else 
    imageData = UIImageJPEGReprensentation(selectedImage);

NSUInteger fileLength = [imageData length];

NSLog(@"file length : [%u]", fileLength);
```

But when I run the code, it print 362788 byte.

Is there anybody who know this?

Comment: Are you sure that the else block executes? That is too big a difference.

Comment: But your condition to check whether it is a PNG file is commented out. Try once by commenting out the if block.

Comment: I checked my condition block. It works correctly.
`UIIamge *selectedImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]; NSData *imageDataPNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectedImage); NSData *imageDataJPG = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage, 1.0f); NSUInteger fileLengthPNG = [imageDataPNG length]; NSUInteger fileLengthJPG = [imageDataJPG length]; dLog(@"-->> fileSizePNG : [%u]", fileLengthPNG); dLog(@"-->> fileSizeJPG : [%u]", fileLengthJPG); ` But output was like that. -->> fileSizePNG : [794372] -->> fileSizeJPG : [362788]

Comment: That approach won't work, at least not with JPEG images. You are recompressing the image, which will not yield the original file size. By the way, what compression quality setting are you using. The `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` function requires two arguments. Your code above won't even compile.

Answer (score 6):

If you have code like this to take a picture:

```
UIImagePickerController *controller = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init] autorelease];
controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
controller.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Then you can retrieve a file size of the picked image in the following way:

```
NSURL *assetURL = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
[library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
    NSLog(@"Size: %lld", asset.defaultRepresentation.size);
} failureBlock:nil];
```

If the source type is `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`, you must save the in-memory image to disk before retrieving its *file* size.

Answer (score 2):

As some commenters have said, even if we assume the methodology is correct you are reprocessing the image anyway so the byte sizes will not match.  I use the following method for JPG images, ymmv for PNG:

```
+ (NSInteger)bytesInImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    return CGImageGetBytesPerRow(imageRef) * CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);    
}
```

The above, as a commenter noted, does return the uncompressed size however.

Comment: This is the uncompressed size; it sounds like the original question was the original compressed size...

Comment: Good point! I may well modify the answer if I can think of a solution.  My first sentence still stands as true though.

Answer (score 0):

here is in Swift 4

```
extension UIImage {

    var memorySize: Int {
        guard let imageRef = self.cgImage else { return 0 }
        return imageRef.bytesPerRow * imageRef.height
    }
}
```